Why year taken from date picker can't be compared to year from Date table?
What i want to do is to filter Date table based on year taken from date picker. Here is my code:
Measure - year taken from date picker:
Selected Date = 
CALCULATE(
   YEAR(MAX( DateTable[Date] )),
   ALLSELECTED( DateTable[Date] )
)

Measure where I try to filter Date table with this variable:
VAR vSelectedDate = [Selected Date]

VAR vCustomersNotInYear =
CALCULATETABLE(
    VALUES('DateTable'[Year]),
    'DateTable'[Year] < vSelectedDate
    )
    
RETURN vCustomersNotInYear

I checked, that measure [Selected Date] returns year properly, it's a number. Year in Date table is also a number. When I change date on a picker then it doesn't work. However, when I assign value manually:
'DateTable'[Year] < 2012

then it works and Date table is filtered. Where is the problem?
PS. I also tried with VALUE([Selected Date]) to enforce (just in case) type conversion but it also doesn't help.
